# UITableView, Editing mode, longpress behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using an `UITableView` with edit mode to insert / delete new cells. Unfortunately I have to click the red-circle for deleting or the green-circle for inserting for a long time before it does anything. On both, device and simulator (Xcode 4.62 and newest SDK & iOS).

It looks like an longpress gesture, but I didn't insert a `UIGestureRecognizer` for those or similar things.

`UITableView` is grouped style; with both, editing and nonEditing cells, vertical scrolling is enabled.

Question is: what can I do for deleting / inserting an cell with short tap on the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Ok - I found the trick. I added an gestureRecognizer for hiding the keyboard ( There's an TextField inside an `UITableViewCell` ). I have to set the `cancelsTouchesInView` to NO.